# how to use an event object to dispaly information about a DOM element

Tags: javascript, events, alert

I want to be able to click on a box (the boxes are created through code, and receive values from a form) in the webpage and display information about the box. I am working on a display() function that uses an event object and an alert to display information about the box. So far, I've had multiple odd failures in my attempt to do this, which leads me to believe that I'm not accessing object attributes correctly. I'm a beginner, so this could be really obvious, but thanks for the help.

constructor function:

```
function Box (counter, name, color, number, coordinates) {  
    this.counter = counter;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.number = number;
    this.coordinates = coordinates; 
}
```

Global variables:

```
var boxes = []; 
var counter = 0;
```

Init function:

```
function init() {     
    var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
    generateButton.onclick = getBoxValues;

    var clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton");
    clearButton.onclick = clear;
}
```

Function that gets values from the form:

```
function getBoxValues() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");  
    var name = nameInput.value; 

    var numbersArray = dataForm.elements.amount;
    for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        if (numbersArray[i].checked) {
            number = numbersArray[i].value;
        }
    }  

    var colorSelect = document.getElementById("color");  
    var colorOption = colorSelect.options[colorSelect.selectedIndex];  
    var color = colorOption.value;                       

    if (name == null || name == "") {                    
        alert("Please enter a name for your box");
        return;
    } else {
        var newbox = new Box(counter, name, color, number, "coordinates");  
        boxes.push(newbox);
        counter++;
        /*for(m = 0; m < boxes.length; m++) {
            counter.newbox = boxes[m];
        }*/
    }

    addBox(newbox);

    var data = document.getElementById("dataForm");               
    data.reset();
}
```

function that assigns attributes to the boxes:

```
function addBox(newbox) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < newbox.number; i++) {                            
        var scene = document.getElementById("scene");              
        var div = document.createElement("div");                  
        div.className += " " + "box"; 
        div.innerHTML += newbox.name; 
        div.style.backgroundColor = newbox.color; 
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));
        div.style.left = x + "px";
        div.style.top = y + "px"; 
        scene.appendChild(div); 
        div.onclick = display; 
        //console.log(newbox); 
        //shows all of the property values of newbox in the console
        //console.log(div); shows that it is an object in the console  
        //console.log(div.hasAttribute(number));  says false               
    }                  
}
```

display function:

```
function display(e) {
    // alert(e.target);  says its an html object
    //alert(e.target.className); works - says "box"
    //alert(e.target.hasAttribute(name)); says false
}
```

I've included some of the things i've found in comments.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear.  You give a vague description of what you're trying to do, an even more vague description of the problem and then just past a whole bunch of code in.  Can you clarify the exact problem and the exact question and connect that to one particular piece of code?  For example, what doesn't work in your current code?  Are you getting script errors in the error console?

Comment: My question is what do I have to change in my display function so that when I click on a box I can get an alert that says the "name" of the box? or the "color" or the "number".

Answer (score 0):

The event object only gives you the name not a reference to the element. So... a couple of things.

First if you want to be browser agnostic you want something like (e.srcElement is for IE):

```
    var x = e.target||e.srcElement;
```

Then get a reference to the element and do what you want:

```
    var refToElement = document.getElementById(x.id);
```

Comment: when i do that it says that i passed an empty string to document.getElementById

Comment: Did you give the element an ID?